# Can I create different versions of a heading format in Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, text-formatting

I'm creating a rather large document and I'm doing my best to use best practices by employing Word's styles to keep all of my formatting consistent. I'm running into one issue, though: I need some of my "Heading 3" headers to look different than the others. I want them all to be Heading 3 so that in the document navigation everything shows up at the right level.

So is there a way to create a new style based on Heading 3 that shows at the same level as H3 in document navigation, but has different formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new style that is based on Heading 3 and change formatting to suit. It should inherit the outline level from Heading 3 so it appears at the same level, however if it doesn't you can set the outline level under Paragraph formatting to "Level 3".